# unlockAchievement - is it silently failing sometimes?

Tags: google-play-games, achievements

unlockAchievement() in Google Play Games is silently failing for me sometimes. It tends to fail when I call it just after signing (when there's a backlog of achievements and a user signs in).

Unfortunately I have no proof. I'm just running my game (after reseting my achievements) and on occasion it fails. I have system outs just before the call to unlockAchievement() - so I know it's getting called.

Just wondering if anybody else is experiencing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a simple experiment.. I started my app and signed in play services.. Then i pressed the home button and turned off my internet connection and went back to my app and submitted my score to play service.. My score submitted in google play services when i again turned on my internet. It shows they have stored your score once signedin even without net connection. so i think i wont fail..

Comment: Hi Zelva,
thanks for trying it out. Since I've asked my question Google has deprecated the GamesClient API I was using - which seemed to be less reliable than the new one that replaced it. It looks like the new one lets you cache requests when you're offline.